# iText 7 c#, ¿cómo agrego mi tabla a una nueva página si no cabe en mi página actual?

Tags: itextsharp

El contenido del documento es variable, en ocasiones la tabla que genero al final no cabe y se muestra (e imprime) cortada. La idea es que si no cabe en la página actual, se agregue otra página nueva y se inserte ahí la tabla. Esta última tabla es pequeña y su tamaño es constante.

De antemano, muchas gracias por sus atenciones.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.